# NUnit testcasesource with data refactored into another class

Tags: nunit, testcasesource

I am using NUnit with the `TestCaseSource` attribute to do data-driven testing with dynamic data in the same approach as [NUnit TestCaseSource pass value to factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287829/nunit-testcasesource-pass-value-to-factory) and
[How can I pass dynamic objects into an NUnit TestCase function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220943/how-to-pass-dynamic-objects-into-an-nunit-testcase-function)

In each case they use `IEnumerable<TestCaseData>`  to specify data.  It appears from the NUnit documentation here http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5 that this needs to be a static or instance member of the same class as the `TestCase`.

I would like to refactor this into another class since I want to use the same `TestCaseSource` attribute.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 23):

Robert already answered it, but I will try to improve his answer with the new features of C#.

```cs
public static class TestCasesData 
{ 
      private static string[] TestStringsData() 
      {
           return new string[] {"TEST1", "TEST2"};
      }
      private static string[] TestIntsData() 
      {
           return new in[] { 1, 2};
      }
}
[TestFixture]
public class MyTest
{
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(typeof(TestCasesData ), nameof(TestCasesData .TestStringsData))]
    public void TestCase1(...)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestCase2(
      [ValueSource(typeof(TestCasesData), "TestIntsData")] int testData,
    )
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 using `nameof` is better than magic strings. If class or method name changes, compiler will redflag it here.

Answer (score 12):

You can do something like:

```
[TestCaseSource(typeof(CommonSource), "GetData")]
public void MyTest(...) {...}
```

The first argument to the attribute constructor tells it which class to look in and the second argument tell it the specific member name to use.

Answer (score 3):

If NUnit requires the TestCaseSource to be in the same class as the tests, the easiest way might be to have that method call your common method.  Then, the details can be kept elsewhere, so you minimize duplicate code.

For example, each test class might have the following:

```
IEnumerable LocalSource()
{
    return CommonSource.GetData();
}
```

The CommonSource class would be a separate class that loads the data necessary for the tests.